# Seeking a super intelligent IDE or coding editor for Linux

Tags: ide, editor

I'm currently using Geany which is pretty good, but I'm looking for something a little more advanced. Preferably I'm after an editor good for web development that is smart enough to change syntax coloring and code completion based on where my cursor is. For instance, I may be editing a .php file, but I could be editing within a block of CSS, HTML, JavaScript, or PHP. Is there an editor smart enough to adjust depending on where I'm editing within a file?

Failing that, I'm looking for an editor that has really great code hinting and completion, even for libraries like jQuery, and it should be flawless at auto indenting, etc.

Thanks!

EDIT: Free solutions only.

Comment: Have a look at Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) if you really just want an editor, for a whole IDE I would recommend Netbeans (http://netbeans.org/index.html) - Both are free and both meet your requirements.

Comment: Notepad++ appears to be Windows only, though, and I was looking for something for Linux.

Comment: @Quasdunk What about Aptana Studio?

Comment: Concerning Notepad++, you can also download the sources, so I thought it would be possible to also compile it on Linux (as you see, I'm not a Linux-expert :-P). Concerning Aptana: When I tried the beta-version of Aptana 3 about 6 month ago, it messed up all my files with a strange encoding or something like that, since then, I've never used it :) But you're right, it's also concerned as on of the leading IDEs for web-development and supports jQuery-code very well. Another nice feature: It shows you all supporting browsers for the html-markup you're just typing. And it's based on Eclipse.

Comment: If you don't want to compile the scripts, there IS an (outdated) installer for linux right here: http://code.google.com/p/npp-installer/

Comment: Does this question belong here?
Assuming it does, I'd say NetBeans, Aptana and Eclipse are probably your best bets.

Comment: Actually, I use Sublime Text 2 now. Love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [NetBeans...](http://netbeans.org/index.html) It is free

Comment: Installed it. I can grab a PHP add-on, but it doesn't seem to really be geared towards HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack Netbeans aure does support all of these languages and even recognises them, even if they're mixed in a php file. I've been working for 1 year with Netbeans now (after testing a few alternatives), and I've never been happier and more productive :)

Comment: @Quasdunk Uhhh yeah, I was wrong. Very nice, I dig it! Now I just need to find out how to add jQuery code support to NetBeans. And maybe update NetBeans to recognize HTML5 and CSS3 stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Try Aptana 3.0 its a good free choice for linux users.
If you already have Eclipse you can just install the Aptana plugin.
http://www.aptana.com/

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is FOSS and has the PHP related functionality you're referring to; it's a great editor but it doesn't have built-in "heavy" IDE functionality like debugging.

PhpED is a great and powerful IDE for pay with a free trial, but it is for PHP and web scripting languages, not a general purpose IDE. It however has very good tools for debugging PHP including allowing you to run a server via PhpED to test your site and allowing you to debug in multiple versions of PHP, and perhaps more importantly a profile to find bottlenecks in your code. Note I've only used the Windows version of PhpED however, I don't know what their linux options are.

If you're doing web development I would think either would suffice, but you won't find features like debugging C++/non web related programming languages in them.